# Different flake8 behaviour locally and in tox

Tags: python, python-3.x, tox, flake8, isort

I have a project which uses `tox`. And I run `flake8` in it. Until now everything worked fine, until I decided to run flake8 on tests also.

When I call `flake8 ./tests` I get some output. Then I can fix it. Now I have no warnings whatsoever in the tests folder. But something strange happens when I run it in tox (I am 100% sure, that the packages like WPS or isort have the same versions as the ones I use locally). Basically I get `isort` warnings. The problem looks like this:

```py
from freezegun import freeze_time

from foo.bar import baz
```

So I have a 3rd party lib import above the import from my lib. And everything is fine here, `vscode` with flake8 installed or running flake8 in terminal both don't give any warnings here. The problem is, I think, that somehow `foo` gets treated like a 3rd party lib here, so e.g. in this case, flake wants me to delete the newline between those two.

I basically tried everything (e.g. `pytest-flake8`, but it's not good, since it also runs tests, which I have in the other tox job). Is there any way to solve this, cuz my pipelines keep falling due to this.

P.S `noqa`ing IXXX warnings is not the solution here, since I want them, but not in a wrong way, which I presented above.

P.S 2 I have `known_first_party=foo` in the `[isort]` section in my `setup.cfg`

Comment: There are various ``flake8`` plugins for import order - which one are you using? Does the real name of ``foo`` conflict with an actual third-party library?

Comment: No, it for sure doesn't. As for the plugins, I have wps and pydocstyle

Answer (score 2):

`isort` is sensitive to the libraries installed adjacent to it -- meaning you ~generally need to install all of your dependencies when using it

there's a few workarounds I've worked on:

- [`seed-isort-config`](https://github.com/asottile/seed-isort-config) (originally for [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com)) - this sets the `known_third_party` to an appropriate list such that `isort` run anywhere with any set of dependencies will still resolve properly
- [`reorder_python_imports`](https://github.com/asottile/reorder_python_imports) - an alternative import sorter which does not suffer from the limitations of `isort` (the machinery that powers this is also the same machinery that powers the import classification in `seed-isort-config`)

(disclaimer: I'm the author of the above tools, I'm also the current `flake8` maintainer)